# How to access the widget id that is inserted into a layout that is load in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, view, widget, adapter

How to access the widget id that is inserted into a layout that is loada in a listview by adapter?

Class:

```
  public class PedidosListActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private static final List<Map<String, Object>> produtos = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    ListView listView;
    NumberPicker _picker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_pedidos_confirmados);
        Map<String, Object> mapProduto = (Map<String, Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("produto");
        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        item.put("imagem_produto", R.drawable.batatafritas);
        produtos.add(item);
        String[] de = {"imagem_produto", "nome_produto", "peso", "preco"};

        int[] para = {R.id.imagem_produto, R.id.nome_produto,
                R.id.peso, R.id.preco};    
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_id)
        _picker = (NumberPicker) listView.findViewById(R.id.npQuantidade);    
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, produtos, R.layout.listview_test, de, para);
          adapter.setViewBinder(this);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom adapter you can put a string extra so that when the user clicks the item in the ListView you pass the information you want.